# Google Charts: How to add a caption to the color axis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, caption

## Adding a Caption to the Bubble Chart Color Axis

In a project I am going to use the Google Chart API for diplaying a bubble chart with three variables. I know how I can change the caption of the axis, but how can I add a caption to the color bar at the top of the chart?

## An Example

I modified the example from the documentation in order to include axis labels. Please not that the original does not have the green caption "How can I add a caption to this bar".

[image: I want to add the caption in green letters at the top of the chart]

This is the original source code from the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart?hl=ja#javascript) where I added the title property for the axis. I tried to add a title property to the colorAxis, but it did not have any effect.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'Temperature'],
          ['',   80,  167,      120],
          ['',   79,  136,      130],
          ['',   78,  184,      50],
          ['',   72,  278,      230],
          ['',   81,  200,      210],
          ['',   72,  170,      100],
          ['',   68,  477,      80]
        ]);

        var options = {
          colorAxis: {colors: ['yellow', 'red']},
          hAxis: { title: "X AXIS" },
          vAxis: { title: "Y AXIS" }

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## My Question

How can I add a caption similar to the image above?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a title for the chart that will be placed just above the `colorAxis` :

```
var options = {
    title: 'How can I add a caption to this bar?',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['yellow', 'red']},
    hAxis: { title: "X AXIS" },
    vAxis: { title: "Y AXIS" }
};
```

It's not exactly the caption of the `colorAxis`, but it can have the same effect.